# Rshiny modular application with reactiveValues has session separation issues

Tags: r, session, shiny, module, reactive

I have a shiny application for which I have reproduced a simple example here.
It is a modular shiny application. This one is deployed on shinyapp.io
**My problem is that when I open 2 instances of my deployed application, the actions done on one of the windows are applied to the other window**

It seems that the problem is caused by the reactiveValues (*r_global <- reactiveValues()* ) in the server part.
Here is the reproduction of the code.

```
library(shiny)

#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#                            MODULE                           ----
#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
counterButton = function(id, label = "Counter") {
  ns = NS(id)
  tagList(actionButton(ns("button"), label = label),
          verbatimTextOutput(ns("out")),
          dataTableOutput(ns("table")))
}

counterServer <- function(id, r_global) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 r_global$count = 0

                 observeEvent(input$button, {
                   r_global$count = r_global$count + 1

                   if (input$button == 3) {
                     output$table <- renderDataTable({
                       mtcars
                     })
                   } else{
                     output$table <- renderDataTable({
                       iris
                     })
                   }
                 })


                 output$out <- renderText({
                   r_global$count
                 })
               })
}

#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#                              UI                             ----
#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
ui = fluidPage(h1("test"), counterButton("counter1", "Counter #1"))


#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#                            SERVER                           ----
#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  r_global <- reactiveValues()
  counterServer("counter1", r_global = r_global)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]